# PDFBox - pdf file page label nullpointer

Tags: java, pdfbox

i would like to ask your help..

so im accessing the page number of a PDF File through this code below

```
this.setfPage(Double.parseDouble(pdfl.getLabelsByPageIndices()[0]));
```

it works fine on all other documents except for one pdf file it gives a NullPointerException pointing on the code above.. im really confused .. is my pdf file the problem?

Comment: Page labels are optional in pdfs. Thus, you indeed have to check and not assume them to be present. That been said, your code line is not very helpful as you don't tell what `this` and `pdfl` are. And your question *is my pdf file the problem* can only be truly answered if you share your pdf.

Comment: it was indeed my PDF File that was the problem. thank you @mkl :)